# Database Replication or Single Point?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, replication, merge-replication

We have a Database and web application hosted in our office in Middle East, and we have 2 more sites in Philippines and USA.

Both offices in Philippines and USA are using the same hosted Web Application and SQL Server in Middle East but we face much latency between Philippines and Middle East due to Internet Speed.

We tried to run Merge Replication between Middle East and Philippines however it took very long time to copy the snapshot from Middle East to PHL.

Our Database Size is around 1.5 TB and we don't have any idea how we can resolve this situation we have now, putting into consideration that we need on the spot update between both Sites as users might be working on the same data at the same time

Any Clue ?

Comment: How big is your connection to your remote sites? What priority on the network is SQL traffic? CIF network traffic is file copy. Make sure SQL server traffic has a higher priority than CIF.